# Link Description crawled property in a display template - SP2013

Tags: 2013, display-template, managed-property, crawled-property

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to display templates, so please bare with me.

I am trying to map the link description from a URL column to my display template. However I have no idea what that property is called. This is probably very simple, but as I said I am a bit of a noob.

I have searched through the crawled properties but cannot find it and am not sure if it is crawled out of the box.

I have tried a few different random mappings to see if the text gets pulled in, but it doesn't return any values. Such as:

```
'Link Text'{Link Text}:'DetailLinkOWSURLH';
```

Then added:

```
var linkText = $getItemValue(ctx, "Link Text");
```

My markup:

```
<div class="slide" data-displaytemplate="ItemLargePicture">
    _#= pictureMarkup =#_
        <div class="caption">
        <h2 class="title"> _#= line1 =#_</h2>
            <p class="text"> _#= line2 =#_</p>
            <p class="link"><a href="_#= linkURL =#_" target="_blank">_#= I NEED THIS VALUE =#_</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, so I checked every single mapped/crawled [EDIT: managed] property that had "url" in it, and I found the one that stores the URL + description: `URLOWSURLH`.
The data that comes back is in form of [url, description], so you should be able to parse it and get the description from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in answer to my own question it seems the URL Description is not a [managed property and cannot be retrieved](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6b4ad7a3-7622-4202-a51f-6b2339133b29/what-does-fast-search-do-with-a-hyperlink-or-picture-column-in-the-index?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

I guess the easiest solution would be to create a new text field for the link text and retrieve that.